# Making a list from equations

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to make a list (efficiently) which is the set of lattice solutions of the following equations (depends on $k$):

$x_0\geq 0$ and $x_i\in [0,4k]$ for $i=1,\ldots,4$ satisfies

$x_0+x_3\leq k+3$, $x_0+x_2+x_3\leq 2k+7$, $x_0+x_1+x_2+x_3\leq 3k+11$, $x_0\leq 15$, $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4k$.

How can I do that?

EDIT: For example, by doing the following I can make a list of (easy) lattice equations:

$x,y\in[1,5]$, $x+y\leq 5$.

```
Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5 - i}], 1]
```

But I want to make this using if sentence.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: What does $0\leq x_1, \ldots, x_4 \leq 4k$ mean? Does it imply that $0 \leq x_i\mbox{ , }i \in [1\mbox{,}4]$? or that all $x_i \leq 4k$?

Comment: I edited my trial and modified notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like :

```
eqs = {x0 + x3 <= k + 3, x0 + x2 + x3 <= 2 k + 7, x0 + x1 + x2 + x3 <= 3 k + 11, 
       x0 <= 15, x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 == 4 k};
vars = {x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};
const = 1 <= # <= 5 & /@ vars;

sol=Solve[Join[eqs /. k -> 1, const], vars, Integers];
```

As suggested by @amr, the values can be obtained with `sol[[All,All,2]]`.

Comment: I want list value data output. (e.g. $\{1,2\}$ not $x\to1, y\to 2$.)

Comment: @user7540 `a -> b` is shorthand for `Rule[a, b]`. you can just do `/. Rule -> List` on the output